# Работа с таймерами в приложении Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

В приложении Xamarin.Forms необходимо реализовать таймер, срабатывающий через заданный интервал времени. При срабатывании таймера должно появляться диалоговое окно-сообщение и срабатывать звуковой сигнал.
Попробовал сделать двумя способами:
1) Использовать метод Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan interval, Func callback);
2) Использовать симуляцию таймера с помощью временной задержки Task.Delay() в вызванном асинхронно методе.

Проблема заключается в том, что таймер существует только до того момента, пока пользователь не перейдет со страницы мобильного приложения, на котором вызывается таймер, на другую страницу. При переходе на другую страницу таймер уничтожается.

Прошу подсказать как сделать таймер, который будет работать при переходе на другую страницу приложения до полного закрытия приложения. Попробовал реализовать таймер внутри App.xaml.cs, но в таком случае не получается вызвать диалоговое окно с сообщением DisplayAlert()

Вот как сделано сейчас:

```
private async void AlarmTimer(string nameRecipe, string nameTimer, int interval)
{
    await Task.Delay(interval);
    DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayAudioFile("alarm.mp3");
    await DisplayAlert("Таймер рецепта " + nameRecipe, "Cработал таймер " + nameTimer + " в " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "Закрыть");
}
```

Установка таймера:

```
AlarmTimer(SelectedRecipe.Name, recipeTiming.Description, 5000);
```

Таймер работает если приложение находится на странице с таймером или странице, вызванной из неё. Но перестает работать при возврате на корневую страницу или предыдущую той, с которой идет вызов.

Думаю проблему бы решило размещение метода таймера на корневой странице и вызов его с вложенной страницы. Не могу только понять как в Xamarin.Forms правильно сделать такой вызов. Прошу подсказать

Answer (score 2):

Пример решения через `Device.StartTimer`

Устройство вызывает `Func callback` каждые 5мс

```
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5), OnTimerTick);
```

Реализация `Func callback`:

```
    private bool OnTimerTick()
    {
        bool alive = true;
        //Делаем что надо
        return alive;
    }
```

`OnTimerTick` - возвращает true - таймер продолжает работу, возвращает false - заканчивает работу.

Если ты вызываешь со страницы с таймером новую страницу, например:

```
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage());
```

Таймер продолжает работу. Если нужно его отключать, делаешь это в `OnAppearing` и не забываешь запускать таймер при возврате на страницу в `OnDisappearing()`.
При навигации, можно все таймеры оставить на корневой странице.

Малость о навигации https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/5.1.php

Вариант 2 - асинхронный метод While(timerEnable) и Task.Delay

```
async public void DrawTimer(int interval)
{

    if (await DisplayAlert("Подтвердите", "Запустить таймер?", "Да", "Нет"))
    {
        timerEnable = true;
        while (timerEnable)
        {
            DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayAudioFile("alarm.mp3");
            await DisplayAlert("Таймер рецепта " + nameRecipe, "Cработал таймер " + nameTimer + " в " + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "Закрыть");
            //что-то делаем
            await Task.Delay(interval);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за вариант. В моём случае он не подходит по ряду причин:

Comment: 1) Мне необходимо передавать при запуске таймера текст, который должен выводится в DisplayAlert при срабатывании таймера. 2) Таймер должен запускаться не из корневой страницы, а со страницы третьего уровня вложения. Соответственно, при возврате на предыдущую или корневую страницу он уже не сработает. Первую проблему я могу решить при использовании асинхронного метода с Task.Delay(), со второй пока не понятно что делать. Выложил свой вариант, может подскажете как вызывать метод AlarmTimer с вложенной страницы, если он будет на корневой странице.

Comment: Можно попробовать передать корневую страницу дочерним, либо только делегат метода. 
Можно попробовать вырвать корневую странизу с методом из стека навигации. [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage.rootpage?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_NavigationPage_RootPage)

Comment: Добавил 2й вариант таймера.

Comment: Что-то пока не получается у меня вырвать корневую страницу с методом из стека навигации. Можно пример как это сделать? Все страницы в приложении типа ContentPage, навигация осуществляется через await Navigation.PushAsync()

Comment: Попробуйте `var root = _currentNavigationPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[0];` [Тут проблема с проверкой наличия конкретной страницы в стеке](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/127493/how-to-check-a-page-is-in-the-navigation-stack-or-not) может поможет.

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал с передачей ссылки на корневую страницу при вызове дочерней, работает.